# How do you check if a JavaScript object is directly an `{}` instance, not a subclass?

Tags: javascript

I have spent 10 or 20 minutes here and there probably a dozen times in the past year and never found a bulletproof answer to this question.

How do you check if a JavaScript object is an instance of `Object`, not a subclass?

One use case for this is to check if `arguments[0]` is an "options" hash vs. a "model" (MVC), both of which extend the native `Object`, but which should be treated differently.

I have tried these:

```
// some helper to get constructor name
function klassName(fn) {
  if (fn.__name__) {
    return fn.__name__;
  }
  if (fn.name) {
    return fn.name;
  }
  return fn.toString().match(/\W*function\s+([\w\$]+)\(/));
};

var Model = function() {};

m = new Model;
o = {};

Object(o) === o; // true
Object(m) === m; // true, thought it might be false

klassName(o.constructor); // Object
klassName(m.constructor); // Model
```

That `klassName(m.constructor)` doesn't work in some cases (can't remember exactly, but maybe a regex.constructor, something like that).  Maybe it does, don't know for sure.

Is there a bulletproof way to tell if something is an `{}` object?

Comment: In JavaScript nothing is bulletproof. Not even the `Bulletproof` function itself. :)

Comment: BTW - JavaScript does not have a **subclass** per-se.  Only constructor functions and prototypes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might something as simple as

```
function isObj( test ) {
    return test.constructor === Object;
}
```

Be what you are looking for?

[Test in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukEEw/7/embedded/js%2Cresult/)

Comment: That works. I was just trying something similar to update my answer. This does work. Is it bulletproof?

Comment: @elclanrs - I suggest using [browserstack](http://browserstack.com) to check each of your targeted browsers.

Comment: @elclanrs - If it doesn't work somewhere, I'll see if I can get it into the answer too.  I tested it in IE 6-9 & Chrome, Firefox, Opera  Latest. This should work for most cases.

Comment: Awesome. It's written in a way that's confusing me, is this the same as `function isObj(test) { return test.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor }`? Or is setting the function property `isObj._constructor` some secret hack?  Otherwise it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: No secret hack, just avoiding having to traverse `Object.prototype` to get to `.constructor` every time you ran `isObj()`. You could probably even get away with just `Object`.  `Object.prototype.constructor === Object` the things you think of after the fact...

Comment: Thanks, added a pull request to underscore: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/569

Answer (score 1):

You mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/ukEEw/

```
var o = {};
var re = /\d/;
var f = function(){};
var d = new Date();

var isObj = function(e){
    return e.toString() === '[object Object]';
};

console.log( isObj(o) ); // True
console.log( isObj(re) ); // False
console.log( isObj(f) ); // False
console.log( isObj(d) ); // False
```

​

Comment: Consider using `Object.prototype.toString.call( obj )` instead of just `obj.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

I would just change one thing

```
var isObj = function(e){
    if(!e) return false; // change this line
    return e.toString() === '[object Object]';
};
```